# HTML comment parsing issue in Windows 10 Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, mark-of-the-web

We generate html file to display swf on browsers. Following is our html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0021)http://www.domain_name.com -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="Keywords" content="xxxxx">
    <meta name="Description" content="">
    <title>test</title> // Title Of The HTML
    <link rel="image_src" href="edge05_thumb.png"> 
    <link rel="viewlet" href="edge05.swf"> // SWF 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            document.onhelp=new Function("return false");
            window.onhelp=new Function("return false");
        // -->
    </script>
...
</html>
```

This code works on all other browsers, but on Edge it shows white screen. From my analysis I found that whenever I remove the comment on the second line `(saved from url=(0021)http://www.domain_name.com)` it works fine.

I tried adding the comment in html but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you provide a reduced HTML file that repros the issue you're seeing in Edge?

Comment: <body >
    <div >
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      var hasReqestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);
      if (hasReqestedVersion) 
      {
            var params = {
   ....
   ....
              };
            swfobject.embedSWF("xxx”, "xxxx",width,height,"10.0.0", null, {}, params); 
      }
      else 
      {
       .....
      }
      //-->
      </script>
     </div>    
 </body>
Here is my code sample,I am seeing the issue (i.e.DetectFlashVer is not defined) at DetectFlashVer(....).

Comment: Instead of pasting code here, please instead host the .html file on [OneDrive](http://onedrive.com).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is linked to your // in the end comment section.

Replace this :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        document.onhelp=new Function("return false");
        window.onhelp=new Function("return false");
    // -->
</script>
```

By this :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     <!--
          document.onhelp=new Function("return false");
           window.onhelp=new Function("return false");
     -->
</script>
```